# What should be equivalent to below code in typescript

Tags: typescript, generics

I was just writing some code with java reference to typescript. I got stuck on below line.

```
Class ABC<? extends XYZ>
```

I know class ABC is using generics.
So the part `? extends XYZ` class. How could we write in typescript.

Comment: maybe class ABC<Any extends XYZ>

Comment: i don't understand what you want class abc to look like... do you just want to extend XYZ?

Comment: It is difficult to make a good suggestion without more context. For example, what is `XYZ` (class, interface, ...)

Comment: See I saw ```add(Collection<? extends E> c)``` as a method in some interface on Java docs. So i was creating an interface in typescript like below

```export interface MyInterface<T> {
    add: (t: T) => boolean;
}```
so how should i declare params in add method

Comment: I tried with ```add: (c: Collection<any extends T>) => boolean;``` but I am getting linting errors.

Comment: `<? extends XYZ>` is a wildcard type argument... I don't think an equivalent exists in TypeScript. If you show more of the code and context maybe we can help.

Comment: In simple word I want to write Collection Interface of Java in typescript

Comment: Please show the code you have so far and what you want it to do

Answer (score 0):

This is a self-explaining example where you have class Ia and class Ib and you have another class expecting anything extending Ia:

```
class  Ia {
 ww: string;
}

class Ib extends Ia {
    dd: number;
}

export default class TestClass <T extends Ia> {
    private attribute: T;
    constructor( ib: T) { this.attribute = ib }

}

new TestClass(new Ib());
```

Hope it helps.